# Add session timeout in webConfig

Tags: vb.net

i need add session timeOut in my web.config, but dont work.

I write in the tag of my web.config for set the timeout to be a 30 minutes, (its wrong?)

```
'<sessionState timeOut="30"/>'
```

i'm using VS 2008 and framework .net 3.5.

Can i help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using forms authentication? This would be proper for forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="40"/>
</authentication>
```

Also, ensure you are matching proper case within your web.config.

```
'<sessionState timeOut="30"/>'
```

should be

```
<sessionState timeout="30"/>
```